# Creating Image Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am having a problem while making a Whack a Mole type game, I am trying to create the images where the mole will appear dynamically, yet there is only a blank white screen where the stack panel is. It is fair to say that I am a noob.

This is my loop where I am trying to create these images:

```
        Image[] ImageArray = new Image[50];
        InitializeComponent();
        //string ImageName = "Image";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            Image Image = new Image();
            ImageArray[i] = Image;
            Image.Name = "Image" + i.ToString();
            StackPanel1.Children.Add(ImageArray[i]);
        }

        //Random Number Generator
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(1, 9);

        //If Random Number is "1" Then Image will display
        if (num == 1)
        {
            ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgNameMole));
            ImageArray[1].Source = MoleImage;
        }
```

This is the StackPanel XAML:

```
    <Window x:Name="Window1" x:Class="WhackaMole.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="468.843" Width="666.045" OpacityMask="#FFF70D0D"                         Icon="mole2.png" Cursor="" >
<Grid OpacityMask="#FF5D1313">
    <Image Margin="422,191,-185,-69" Source="mole2.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"             VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Width="595" FontSize="50" FontFamily="SimHei"><Run Language="en-ca" Text="Can You Catch the Mole?"/></TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="NewGameBttn" Content="New Game" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,0,0,16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="139" Height="50" FontSize="25" Click="NewGameBttn_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="CloseBttn" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,365,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Height="50" FontSize="29" Click="CloseBttn_Click"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="231" Margin="35,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What is the value of `ImgNameMole`? Also, is this image in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that since you are adding the items to a `StackPanel`, the `StackPanel` is choosing the default mins for height and width on the image (which is probably 0), and that is why you are not seeing anything.

Try setting a value for the Height and Width of the image and see if anything shows.

Also, as Tejas pointed out you are not setting the image source.

EDIT: Set the Image width like this:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Width = 25;
myImage.Height = 25;
```

Do something like this in your for-loop where you first create the images.

Comment: I have a height and width set in the XAML :(

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the height and width for each image in xaml.  Did you mean you set the height and width for the stackpanel?

Comment: Oh, yes. How would I set the image size? Sorry I am new to this :/

Comment: OH MAN THANK YOU! I'VE BEEN WORKING ON THIS FOR FOREVER! :)

Comment: No prob. I've been bitten many times with the StackPanel using default min values :)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell you're creating a new object of type `Image` but that `Image` really doesn't have anything to display. You need to set the `Source` of your `Image`. Here's an example stolen from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("myPicture.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myImage);
```

As townsean pointed out, you should probably create a `Style` for your `Image` where you can set common properties such as `Height`, `Width` etc.

Comment: doh, I totally overlooked that part too :P I'll need to update my answer

Comment: Later on in the program I am giving the ImageArray a value, I will edit my question.

Comment: Then perhaps something is wrong with your `Uri`? Try specifying `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` in the constructor for `Uri` If that doesn't fix it, please post your xaml.

Comment: I'll add the XAML to the question :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post a little bit more? That one line is not much to go by.